# firebug net tab 0 request problem

Tags: javascript, firebug

I've step into a problem with firebug,

say under the "Net" tab,it always shows "0 request"

But I've already "enabled monitor for xxx"

Has any one met the same problem before?

What can I do to make "Net" tab return to normal again?

Answer (score 1):

You probably aren't looking at "all". Above the "Net" tab is another set of Tabs (All, HTML, CSS, JS, XHR, Images, Flash) You probably have one of these selected.

I'd laugh, but I've had this happen to me before as well.

Comment: Thank you ,that's exactly the case!